# Swift - How can I generalize this method into my superclass?

Tags: generics, inheritance, swift, methods, struct

I'm pre allocating resources for a game.  I have one superclass BaseScene, and two children GameScene, and HyperScene.

GameScene and HyperScene both preload their resources on another thread, but the method they use to do this is basically identical.

**GameScene**

```
class func createResources(config: GameSceneConfig, withCompletion: (scene: GameScene) -> ()){

    // load resources on other thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {

        self.createTextures()  // need to load textures before scene is created
        let gameScene = GameScene(config: config)

        // callback on main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            // Call the completion handler back on the main queue.
            withCompletion(scene: gameScene)
        });
    })
}
```

**BaseScene**

```
class func createResources(config: HyperSceneConfig, withCompletion: (scene: HyperScene) -> ()){

    // load resources on other thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {

        self.createTextures()
        let hyperScene = HyperScene(config: config)

        // callback on main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            // Call the completion handler back on the main queue.
            withCompletion(scene: hyperScene)
        });
    })

}
```

config is a struct containing parameters. HyperScene and GameScene each have their own special struct. Inside my `createResources` method I'm pretty sure I can declare a `BaseScene`, and then cast it out as one of its children when calling the method.   It seems like most of the difficulty lies in passing in a generic struct.

here are the two structs

```
struct HyperSceneConfig {
    var size: CGSize
    var viewController: GameViewController

    init(size: CGSize, viewController: GameViewController){
        self.size = size
        self.viewController = viewController
    }
}


struct GameSceneConfig {
    var size: CGSize
    var viewController: GameViewController
    var curLevel: Int
    var curSector: Int
    var lives: Int

    init(size: CGSize, viewController: GameViewController, curSector: Int, curLevel: Int, lives: Int = 3, startPoint: CGPoint? = nil){
        self.size = size
        self.viewController = viewController
        self.curLevel = curLevel
        self.curSector = curSector
        self.lives = lives
    }
}
```

HyperScene takes the first one as a parameter.  GameScene takes the second one.

Comment: Could you just have a function for loading the scene that takes a string? So where you have `let hyperScene = HyperScene(config: config)` and `let gameScene = GameScene(config: config)` just replace that with a loadSceneName(sceenName)? And just update your withCompletion to take the same string. You can also convert strings into Selectors. You could also pass in callbacks instead of strings

Comment: if i chose to do it this way id still have trouble passing config into the method since each class accepts a different type of struct

Comment: Make them extend from the same class and give them generic methods. Override those in the subclass and you can accept any config type parameter.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about the `config` and the two scenes?

Comment: i edited my question to show the structs.  do you need more info?

Comment: No, that's exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make your `GameSceneConfig` and `HyperSceneConfig` extend from the same class. Then just call their generic initializer.

Edit your

```
class func createResources(config: GameSceneConfig, withCompletion: (scene: GameScene) -> ())
```

To

```
class func createResources(config: configName, withCompletion: (scene: GameScene) -> ()) ->())
```

Where you have

let hyperScene = HyperScene(config: config)

That becomes

```
let scene = sceneInit(config: configName)
```

And create a sceneInit that handles whatever needs you have for a scene.

Comment: they arent classes, theyre structs.  structs dont have inheritance

Comment: Make them into a class. Also note that in Swift structs can have functions.

Comment: i'd rather do this through the use of generics if possible.  I know I can somehow make this happen by playing with the types of variables and having conditional statements etc.  But it doesnt seem much cleaner than what I'm currently doing